# AFNetworking 2.0 setImageWithURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking

I'm using this code when downloading images in one of my current projects and it's not working with AFNetworking 2.0. I tried going thru AFImageResponseSerializer but I can't find the right code to use.

```
[cell.posterImage setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
            cell.posterImage.image = image;
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@", error);
        }];
```

Any suggestions on the new code used in AFNetworking 2.0? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I made it work using this code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *posterOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
posterOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[posterOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    _posterImageView.image = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image request failed with error: %@", error);
}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:posterOperation];
[posterOperation start];
```

But I got into another problem with placeholder images using this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`UIImageView (AFNetworking)` category](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html).

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"

//...
[cell.posterImage setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        cell.posterImage.image = image;
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@", error);
    }];
```

`cell.posterImage` must be an `UIImageView` not an `UIImage`.

Comment: Have you followed the first link in the answer? It is pretty clear documentation for AFNetworking 2.0: UIImageView(AFNetworking) Category Reference. I'd appreciate if you don't down vote people if you are not sure of what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

With the updated `AFNetworking 2.0` (in case your files are accessible for download-only basis, so are not accessible by a simple URL) :

```
NSString * methodURL = @"http://www.yourserver.com/pathToImageDownloadMethod";
NSInteger someIDYouHaveOfAnImage = 13;
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary * parameterDictionary = @{@"Parameter" : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:someIDYouHaveOfAnImage]};
[manager GET:methodURL parameters:parameterDictionary success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
        UIImage * image = responseObject;
        // Here is your image object
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure getting the file : %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i use your method but i dont need to pass any parameter how can i do that , thank you

Comment: you can just pass `nil` whend sending the parameter. Like this : `[manager GET:methodURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPReques ...`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/archive/master.zip is including UIKit+AFNetworking directory