# What is the header file for AFImageRequestOperation in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

i am trying to run this code:

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"

AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
     NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseData); // Data
     NSLog(@"%@", [responseObject class]); // UIImage
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}];
```

But having these errors:

> Unknown type name `AFImageRequestOperation`; did you mean `AFHTTPRequestOperation`? 
>   Unknown receiver `AFImageRequestOperation`; did you mean `AFHTTPRequestOperation`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172543/afnetworking-2-0-setimagewithurlrequest

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [this github issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1434):

> Now, you'd use a regular AFHTTPRequestOperation and set its
>   responseSerializer to an AFImageResponseSerializer object (probably
>   [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer]).
>
> You can read the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide) to know about this whole
>   serialization idea.